# Fastlane screenshot failed

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I'm trying to take screenshots with fastlane. I don't need to send to itunes connect at this moment. I'm trying only to take screenshots, but I'm getting "test failed'.

There's my Snapfile:

```
# A list of devices you want to take the screenshots from
devices([
   "iPhone 6",
   "iPhone 6 Plus",
   "iPhone 5s",
   "iPhone 4s",
])

languages([
  “pt”
])

# The name of the scheme which contains the UI Tests
scheme “Consultor”

# Where should the resulting screenshots be stored?
output_directory "./screenshots"

clear_previous_screenshots true # remove the '#' to clear all previously generated screenshots before creating new ones

# Choose which project/workspace to use
workspace “././Consultor.xcworkspace"
```

and there's my fastfile:

```
        # Customise this file, documentation can be found here:
    # https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/fastlane/docs
    # All available actions: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Actions.md
    # can also be listed using the `fastlane actions` command

    # Change the syntax highlighting to Ruby
    # All lines starting with a # are ignored when running `fastlane`

    # If you want to automatically update fastlane if a new version is available:
    # update_fastlane

    # This is the minimum version number required.
    # Update this, if you use features of a newer version
    fastlane_version "1.88.0"

    default_platform :ios

    platform :ios do
      before_all do
        # ENV["SLACK_URL"] = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/..."
        cocoapods

      end

      desc "Runs all the tests"
      lane :test do
        scan
      end


  desc "Take screenshots"
  lane :screenshot do
    snapshot
  end



  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Apple TestFlight"
  desc "This will also make sure the profile is up to date"
  lane :beta do
    # match(type: "appstore") # more information: https://codesigning.guide
    gym # Build your app - more options available
    pilot

    # sh "your_script.sh"
    # You can also use other beta testing services here (run `fastlane actions`)
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the App Store"
  lane :appstore do
    # match(type: "appstore")
    # snapshot
    gym # Build your app - more options available
    deliver(force: true)
    # frameit
  end

  # You can define as many lanes as you want

  after_all do |lane|
    # This block is called, only if the executed lane was successful

    # slack(
    #   message: "Successfully deployed new App Update."
    # )
  end

  error do |lane, exception|
    # slack(
    #   message: exception.message,
    #   success: false
    # )
  end
end


# More information about multiple platforms in fastlane: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Platforms.md
# All available actions: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Actions.md

# fastlane reports which actions are used
# No personal data is recorded. Learn more at https://github.com/fastlane/enhancer
```

My project is wrote in swift and ther's my Test Classes: ConsultorUITests:

```
    //
//  SnapshotHelper.swift
//  Example
//
//  Created by Felix Krause on 10/8/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Felix Krause. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import XCTest

var deviceLanguage = ""
var locale = ""

@available(*, deprecated, message="use setupSnapshot: instead")
func setLanguage(app: XCUIApplication) {
    setupSnapshot(app)
}

func setupSnapshot(app: XCUIApplication) {
    Snapshot.setupSnapshot(app)
}

func snapshot(name: String, waitForLoadingIndicator: Bool = true) {
    Snapshot.snapshot(name, waitForLoadingIndicator: waitForLoadingIndicator)
}

public class Snapshot: NSObject {

    public class func setupSnapshot(app: XCUIApplication) {
        setLanguage(app)
        setLocale(app)
        setLaunchArguments(app)
    }

    class func setLanguage(app: XCUIApplication) {
        guard let prefix = pathPrefix() else {
            return
        }

        let path = prefix.stringByAppendingPathComponent("language.txt")

        do {
            let trimCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
            deviceLanguage = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(trimCharacterSet) as String
            app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLanguages", "(\(deviceLanguage))"]
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't detect/set language...")
        }
    }

    class func setLocale(app: XCUIApplication) {
        guard let prefix = pathPrefix() else {
            return
        }

        let path = prefix.stringByAppendingPathComponent("locale.txt")

        do {
            let trimCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
            locale = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(trimCharacterSet) as String
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't detect/set locale...")
        }
        if locale.isEmpty {
            locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: deviceLanguage).localeIdentifier
        }
        app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLocale", "\"\(locale)\""]
    }

    class func setLaunchArguments(app: XCUIApplication) {
        guard let prefix = pathPrefix() else {
            return
        }

        let path = prefix.stringByAppendingPathComponent("snapshot-launch_arguments.txt")
        app.launchArguments += ["-FASTLANE_SNAPSHOT", "YES", "-ui_testing"]

        do {
            let launchArguments = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\\".+?\\\"|\\S+)", options: [])
            let matches = regex.matchesInString(launchArguments, options: [], range: NSRange(location:0, length:launchArguments.characters.count))
            let results = matches.map { result -> String in
                (launchArguments as NSString).substringWithRange(result.range)
            }
            app.launchArguments += results
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't detect/set launch_arguments...")
        }
    }

    public class func snapshot(name: String, waitForLoadingIndicator: Bool = true) {
        if waitForLoadingIndicator {
            waitForLoadingIndicatorToDisappear()
        }

        print("snapshot: \(name)") // more information about this, check out https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot

        sleep(1) // Waiting for the animation to be finished (kind of)
        XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .Unknown
    }

    class func waitForLoadingIndicatorToDisappear() {
        let query = XCUIApplication().statusBars.childrenMatchingType(.Other).elementBoundByIndex(1).childrenMatchingType(.Other)

        while (0..<query.count).map({ query.elementBoundByIndex($0) }).contains({ $0.isLoadingIndicator }) {
            sleep(1)
            print("Waiting for loading indicator to disappear...")
        }
    }

    class func pathPrefix() -> NSString? {
        if let path = NSProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_HOST_HOME"] as NSString? {
            return path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Library/Caches/tools.fastlane")
        }
        print("Couldn't find Snapshot configuration files at ~/Library/Caches/tools.fastlane")
        return nil
    }
}

extension XCUIElement {
    var isLoadingIndicator: Bool {
        return self.frame.size == CGSize(width: 10, height: 20)
    }
}

// Please don't remove the lines below
// They are used to detect outdated configuration files
// SnapshotHelperVersion [1.2]
```

and finally, the terminal logs:

> ` ▸ Building Pods/Alamofire [Debug] ▸ Check Dependencies ▸ Building
>   Pods/Gloss [Debug] ▸ Check Dependencies ▸ Building Pods/JGProgressHUD
>   [Debug] ▸ Check Dependencies ▸ Building Pods/Pods-Consultor [Debug] ▸
>   Check Dependencies ▸ Building Consultor/Consultor [Debug] ▸ Check
>   Dependencies ▸ Running script 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' ▸ Running
>   script 'Embed Pods Frameworks' ▸ Running script 'Copy Pods Resources'
>   ▸ Running script 'Run Script' ▸ Building Consultor/ConsultorTests
>   [Debug] ▸ Check Dependencies ▸ Building Consultor/ConsultorUITests
>   [Debug] ▸ Check Dependencies ▸ Compiling ConsultorUITests.swift ▸
>   Linking ConsultorUITests ▸ Generating 'ConsultorUITests.xctest.dSYM' ▸
>   Touching ConsultorUITests.xctest
>   ** TEST FAILED **
>
> All tests [08:49:30]: Exit status: 65 [08:49:30]: Tests failed - check
>   out the log above [08:49:30]: Tests failed, re-trying 1 out of 2
>   times`

Comment: Does this test pass if run via Xcode? TEST FAILED is output that is generated by xcodebuild, so fastlane is just reporting the results of trying to run your test code here.